# Phonegap project import into Android Studio resulting in plugin errors

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to import a Phonegap app into Android Studio from Eclipse and so far it goes smoothly until I start adding my plugins. The two plugins in question are

[Sqlite Plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)

[Pushwoosh](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin)

I added them using the npm CLI and when I do a `phonegap build` in my project directory and fire my emulator back up, I start getting various errors (about 73 total) stating that the classes in these two files cannot be found.

For example:

> Error:(368, 7) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class SQLiteConnection
>     location: class io.liteglue.SQLitePlugin.SQLiteDatabaseNDK
>
> Error:(28, 37) java: package com.arellomobile.android.push does not exist
>
> Error:(31, 49) java: package com.arellomobile.android.push.PushManager does not exist

The plugins are showing up in my config.xml file. I'm fairly new to the whole Phonegap/Android Studio world, so I was hoping someone could point out anything that I'm missing to solve this problem.